# How can I kill the ant queen with the Story party?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

I'm about level 34 and I'm having trouble killing her on hard mode. I've destroyed all the eggs in her room, so extra FOEs aren't the problem. My general strategy is:

- Arthur spams the single target ice spell and is my main damage dealer.
- Ricky spams ice rounds when she's not busy using medic bullets to remove panic or blindness from a single target.
- Simon takes care of healing and tries to keep poison on her.
- Raquna mostly puts up defensive buffs. I've got a grimoire in her that she uses to debuff the queen's attacks and defense.
- My highlander tries to help with Spear Assist, but burns through TP too fast to do it often.

The battle starts out okay. But by the time we get her to half health, which takes about 8 rounds, my highlander is out of TP, Simon is furiously healing to keep up with her attacks and debuffs, Ricky is on half-time duty helping with debuff removal via Medic Bullet, and everyone is missing most of their attacks due to her high evade which rarely seems to come down. By the time she's at about 40% health, Arthur is about the only one who has time to even damage to her, and that's when he's not dead, blinded, or panicked.

One problem is that I don't have any amritas available for TP recovery, making the fight harder, but the bigger problem is that once she starts evading my overall damage per round drops to almost nothing.

What strategies can I employ to overcome her? Are there any story character skills I should be using to make this easier?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the level of costumization for EOU story characters, so I just put this as a comment: If you have access to binds, USE THEM! Binding legs lowers speed and evasion (sounds very helpful here), arms usually most physical attacks and head most special skills (results may vary). They don't have a large chance to succeed against FOEs and even less against bosses, but they are often extremely helpful.

Comment: @Humungus Thanks for the tip. The only leg bind available to me is the gunner, who only has 3 points in it. I landed it twice in about 10 attempts, so eventually gave up. The items that cause leg binds (which I forget the name of) are similarly low-chance. Respeccing to put 10 points in it might make it more worthwhile, however. There may be another story class with a leg bind that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good general strategy I have found that works for most bosses and is nearly unstoppable in random encounters:

**Setting up:**

**Highlander:**
First skill you should max out on Seamus O'Leary O'Malley O'Toole is Bloody Offence, as it is a ridiculously good force multiplier: 50% extra damage at the cost of some health? Yes please.

I haven't used Spear Assist, so I'm not sure about that, but Delayed Charge and Cross Charge are outrageous damage dealers. Head Pierce deals good damage on your interim turns while waiting for Delayed Charge to run down (more damage the longer it goes without activating) and has the added benefit of potentially binding heads, which decreases elemental resists.

**Raquna:**
Max out Shield Mastery to increase her defence and get access to Bravery's Gift, which will also give her Front Guard along the way. Add a point to Provoke and Fortify and dump the rest into HP Up and DEF Up.

**Simon:**
Not much to say about Simon. Four points into Salve, one into Delayed Heal, and however many you want into TP Up. At this point I had maxed Salvage, so that's ten points you may want to put elsewhere.

**Arthur:**
I kept Arthur balanced with his elemental spells, so I think I had Ice Formula at 5 at this point. Extra points into TP Up is always a good idea, as well as maxing out Formula Mastery. One or two points into Cocytus Formula may help with the ants running around. Getting his damage as high as possible is the name of the game.

**Ricky:**
If you can get her Snipe skills up to level 5 they'll have a better chance of hitting those sweet binds. Points into her elemental Shots are good, too, for extra damage.

**The fight:**
Go in with full everything and use Elderevenge. Elderevenge is ideal because it greatly increases the amount of time Arthur can sling Formulae without needing to throw Amrita at him. If he's dealing enough damage, in fact, you'll never have to use an Amrita on him. Take a few Medica IIs and maybe a Soma or two if you have them lying around.

This fight basically boils down to doing the right stuff at the right time, which is relatively easy in this case:

Your **Highlander** should use Bloody Offence on the back line on turn one, then Delayed Charge, then Bloody Offence on the front line, then Head Pierce, then Cross Charge and start the process over, throwing around healing items for Raquna when need be. The most important thing is to keep Bloody Offence up on Arthur and Ricky at all times.

**Raquna** should lead with Provoke, then follow it with Fortify and then Front Guard every turn for eternity. The exception is if somebody is in danger of dying, in which case you use Bravery's Gift to shield that party member. If Raquna is at low health on a turn she uses Bravery's Gift have the Highlander or Ricky throw a Medica II at her.

**Simon** heals every turn, no exceptions. If you have it, alternate Delayed Heal with Salve, otherwise just use Salve every turn. If he runs low on TP have Ricky throw an Amrita his way. If Arthur gets blinded, take a break from restoring HP to cast Refresh on him. At no point should Simon even think about doing anything that might be considered offensive.

**Arthur** will spend every turn throwing Ice Formula at the Queen Ant. If the Queen has a lot of health left and the other ants show up to the party, throw Cocytus Formula a couple of times. If her health is low, pound away with single-target; if the Queen goes down, the fight is done. Arthur will be losing health every turn from Bloody Offence, but he'll heal it right back with the Elderevenge buff.

**Ricky** is the odd man out, so to speak. You can try to bind the Queen's head and arms with Head Snipe and Arm Snipe, but these probably won't work too often. If you're having a lot of trouble getting the binds to stick, have Ricky use Ice Shot instead, as it can deal a lot of damage depending on its level. Ricky should also be your gal Friday for item usage; if Raquna needs extra health to survive a round of Bravery's Gift or if Simon's running low on TP have Ricky toss an appropriate item in the appropriate direction.

Bloody Offence is kind of the linchpin of this whole strategy, because it is just that good. Basically it shaves off a third of the fight: for example, if a fight would normally take 12 turns, Bloody Offence will reduce that to a mere 8. And it gets better the more powerful your enemy is.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up beating this with pretty much the strategy above but some respeccing of my Highlander and Simon.

### The Highlander

The Highlander was respecced to max out Limitless to go along with my maxed out Spear Assist, so that I could make the most of those few hits I'd get. More importantly, though, whereas previous I only had one point in HP Up for him, I now put 8 points in HP Up. This made a big difference in keeping him alive during the Ant Queen's hammer attack. After blowing his TP early on some Limitless Spear Assists, he basically just sat in front and defended or used items on others when needed.

### Raquna

Raquna's main job was to keep Defender up on everyone (which I only have 1 point in), as well as the two Curses she got from a grimoire. One lowers all enemies elemental/physical defense, and the other lowers all enemies elemental/physical defense. She spent the whole fight cycling through these skills, occasionally having to do a Defend if there was a round where she was low on health and I was worried about her dying before the heal got to her. She's got about 5 points in HP Up, which probably helped. Honestly, the rest of her spec probably didn't come into play. She never even attacked.

### Simon

One big change that helped is that I respecced Simon to have 10 points into his poison skill, as well as more in TP Up so that he'd have a larger TP Pool. Previously when I was failing, he only had 1 point in TP Up and 5 in Poison. Another change is whereas previous I was specced with 5 points in Refresh and 5 in Unbind so that I could get Immunize, I just left those skills at 1 point each. This made them single-target and cheaper to use, which was a big help in this fight, as really the only guys I was worried about unblinding were Simon and Ricky. The larger TP pool, less TP waste on Refresh, and more effective poison were probably the biggest game changer for me. I suppose some Therica B's would have done the trick too, though.

### Ricky

Ricky's spec also didn't come into play much. I had one point in Medic Bullet and 1 point in Ice Rounds, which were mainly what she used. She was the one in charge of getting the Panic debuff off someone, since Medic Bullet is a cheap way to remove an ailment with a little healing thrown in as a bonus, and her agility means it usually happens before they attack any of your party members while panicked.

### Arthur

Arthur could have been more effective, but I didn't want to respec him if I didn't need to. He had 4 points in Ice Formula, and pretty much just spammed that the whole fight. I had a grimoire on him that would let him cast Refresh in a pinch, but he never used it. Getting a 5th point in Ice Formula for the nice damage boost probably would have helped, since he had 10 points in TP Up and was never in danger of running out, but I was unwilling to respec him for a 1 point bump.

### General Strategy

For the food buff, I choose the buff that increases max HP. One thing I'd been noticing is that her multi-hit attack would occasionally get lucky and take out one of my front-liners (the Highlander and Raquna), and it would all go downhill after that as I tried to revive them and get them healed. So between respeccing the Highlander for more health and this buff, as well as having my front-liners defend if they were ever at half health or less, it helped make sure they stayed alive and soaking hits for everyone else.

So basically, combat was my Highlander blowing Limitless and Spear Assists in the early rounds until he was out of TP, and then defending. Raquna was on buff/debuff duty. Simon kept poison up and did heals. Arthur did slow and steady ice damage. Ricky cured occasional debuffs and spammed ice rounds. When she'd throw up her skill that did high evasion, I'd basically hunker down for a few rounds and have people defend rather than blow TP on attacks that probably wouldn't hit anyway. When boosts came up, I saved them until I knew her evade had worn off. In particular, when Simon would land a boosted poison on her, it would do 400-500 damage a round for 3-4 rounds. Very nice!

We ended up using the one Amrita I had on Simon. I think I also used one Nectar when she took Arthur out with an unexpected shot. Other than that, we pretty much just slowly burned her down. I think having enough HP on the front line to make sure they didn't die was the overall key to success.

---

A few things of note for this boss fight

- She is weak to ice attacks.
- Every 5 rounds (so round 5, 10, 15, etc) she casts panic on one party member. It's a nice break from her otherwise relentless damage, and this is usually the round I'd use to have Simon put poison on her again, since I knew his heals wouldn't be needed.
- You don't have to fight any additional FOEs with her. When you first get to her, charge straight ahead to the egg she just laid and smash it. Then walk forward and right to get the next one she lays. Then back up a step, turn south, and move forward and you'll end up right where she's about to lay another, giving you the opportunity to attack her with a free first round. If you screw it up or ants are already marching around in here, just go back to town, rest and the inn, and come back. That should clear them out.

Answer (score -1):

I beat her after I reset my highlander job to highlander, it's lv 25 and I didn't put any weapon or equips on him. My Ricky is lv 34, Arthur lv 35, Simon lv 34 and Raquela lv 33. Use Simon's skill that heal all party while Ricky and Arthur spam ice damage. Raquela spam provoke and my highlander just fist cause I forgot to equip him. It ends in less then 10 move. Easy boss just clear her egg and it will be no problem.